# Change immutable builder constructor to use generics

Tags: java, generics, builder-pattern

I have a following class which is a basic DTO for child classes. I need to fix protected constructor because Intellij says: 'raw use of parameterized class builder'.
Can someone please take a look and point how to re-write this constructor to support generic style here.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonPOJOBuilder;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY;

@JsonDeserialize(builder = PageableResponse.Builder.class)
public class PageableResponse<T>
{
    @JsonProperty(value = "data", required = true, access = READ_ONLY)
    private final List<T> data;
    @JsonProperty(value = "total", required = true, access = READ_ONLY)
    private final Long total;

    // constructor required for spring
    public PageableResponse(List<T> data, Long total)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.total = total;
    }

    // here is an issue: Raw use of parameterized class Builder
    protected PageableResponse(Builder builder)
    {
        data = (List<T>) builder.data; // and here unchecked cast as well
        total = builder.total;
    }

    public static <T extends Builder<T>> Builder<T> newBuilder()
    {
        return new Builder<T>();
    }

    public static <T extends Builder<T>> Builder<T> newBuilder(PageableResponse<T> copy)
    {
        Builder<T> builder = new Builder<T>();
        builder.data = copy.getData();
        builder.total = copy.getTotal();
        return builder;
    }

    public List<T> getData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    public Long getTotal()
    {
        return total;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }
        PageableResponse<?> that = (PageableResponse<?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(data, that.data) && Objects.equals(total, that.total);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hash(data, total);
    }

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>
    {
        private List<T> data;
        private Long total;

        protected Builder()
        {
        }

        public Builder<T> data(List<T> data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder<T> total(Long total)
        {
            this.total = total;
            return this;
        }

        public PageableResponse<T> build()
        {
            return new PageableResponse<T>(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Do you think it is possible? Does someone seeing potential issues with this code?

Comment: You can see that there is no `<` after the word `Builder` on that line, right?  That aside, I suspect `T extends Builder<T>` is not what you really want to do.  You probably just want `public static class Builder<D>`.  (You could use `<T>`, but it would be confusing, since the Builder class is entirely separate from the PageabgleResponse class, and their generic types are unrelated, whether or not they use the same letter.)

Comment: Did you try? What was the result?

Answer (score -2):

You can fix the warning by adding the type parameter to your `PageResponse(Builder)` constructor.

```
protected PageableResponse(Builder<T> builder)
```

Additionally the type parameter definition for your `Builder` is a bit weird.

```
public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>
```

Implicates `T` has to be a `Builder`.

```
public static class Builder<T>
```

Means `T` can be anything. Probably makes more sense?

Comment: "_Means T can be anything_" this is a misleading statement. `T` doesn't mean that the parameter can be anything. It means that ALL parameters used must be of whatever type `T` is. That's a different statement. For example, on a `List<T>` (read "_list of type T_"), the parameters can't be anything because `List<T>` is not the same as `List<Object>`.

Comment: I am referring to the type parameter of the class and not to a variable of type `T`. The type parameter `T` in the second example can be anything (as long as it's an object) while a variable like `List<T>` can only be a list of type T as you mentioned.